# WPF Webbrowser using multiple sessions when open more than once

Tags: wpf, browser

We have a WPF webbrowser on one of our detail windows. The detail window gets opened when the user clicks on a search result so there can and will be multiple detail windows open with this webbrowser embedded. The URL is pointing to a Java based application that requires a license and is configured with NTLM to authenticate users.

The first open window is fine, but if you open more the java app gives an error that all licenses are used. In IE everything is fine, you can open multiple windows of this java app and work away.

Is there something I can configure on the webbrowser to use only one session and then clear everything when you close the main window?

**Edit: Note from the Vendor of the Java app that when a browser connects the JBoss server creates a JSessionID and that every other connection from that computer should use the same JSessionID even different browsers. The WPF control is doing something else because it is creating a session for every open view.

**Edit: The initial details I put are incorrect. The view that contains the browser control is a UserControl not a window.

**Edit: If I have no sessions and launch IE/firefox etc to open the Java app I can get a license and use the app. Now that I have a session if I try to use the WebBrowser control it will try to create a new session and I will get an error about the license. If I close the view and the browser windows and try to connect again I am again prompted with a license error as if the browser control is somehow not releasing that session.

I can post the code, but I don't see how that will help as its just a straightforward xaml insertion of the control with the source value set to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can separate each window/browsing session into a different appdomain?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx

On exit of the window, you could throw out that appdomain and the resources used within.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and manually handle initial connectivity and then use [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to render the result. Something like this:

```
String responseString;

HttpWebRequest request = build you request, incorporate session token, etc
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
browser.NavigateToString(responseString);
```

EDIT:

Using cookies, [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/e43239f3-3914-43ec-ac50-223b022ec2ea):

```
public partial class WebBrowserControl : Form
{
        private String url;

        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

        public WebBrowserControl(String path)
        {
            this.url = path;
            InitializeComponent();

            // set cookie
            InternetSetCookie(url, "JSESSIONID", Globals.ThisDocument.sessionID); 

            // navigate
            webBrowser.Navigate(url); 
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and let you know... Thanks

Comment: How do I get the session token from IE or another browser. This is the issue. I'm sure the code works fine, it's getting that JSessionID from IE, firefox or even chrome if its already open and connected to JBoss. Further if I open the JBoss using the WPF browser how do I give that session cookie back to the other browsers again.

Comment: What happens if you open IE and then open Firefox? Does the connection work in both browsers at the same time? You cannot really share cookies or sessions between browsers.

Comment: You're right it doesn't work in FF once its open in IE. I thought though that the WPF to IE portion would work at least. So it seems there is no way for this to work with JBoss and JSessionID??

Comment: @John: You should be able to have access to the JSessionId that is persisted in the cookie in both IE and WebBrowser control. I added an example how you use cookies in WebBrowser control.

Comment: Thanks for all your help thus far... now to throw another curve your way. I am confined within my groups standards and must use WPF and MVVM so I'm not sure the partial class using Windows Forms will work for us. Thanks again you've been very helpful.

Comment: @John: If you talking about cookies then there is no dependency on Windows Forms. InternetSetCookie/InternetSetCookieEx functions are defined in wininet.dll. You can easily access these functions from within WPF application or WPF control. Just import the dll as shown in the code above using DllImport.